# Delphi, MS Access, ADO: "a query to a query with parameters" doesn't give proper result

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado, tadoquery

Please help me to understand what is happening.
Suppose there are following items in an Access database:

table *MyTable*: `IDLine` (auto-increment field), `a`, `b` (integers), and there is a line with `IDLine = 4` in this table.

query *MyQuery*:

```
 SELECT IDLine, a+b AS Sum
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE IDLine >= :MinLine;
```

- i.e. a query that counts some statistics for *MyTable* and also selects some lines using a parameter.

Then in Delphi a TADOQuery is created:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyQuery
WHERE IDLine = :IDLine;
```

and the program is as follows:

```
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('MinLine').Value := 2;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('IDLine').Value := 4;
ADOQuery1.Open;
ShowMessage(IntToStr(ADOQuery1.RecordCount));
```

For some reason the message gives 0, but there should be 1 line. Why is this happening?

If I change the text of ADOQuery1 to

```
SELECT *
FROM MyQuery
WHERE IDLine = 4;
```

the message gives 1.
Also, if I delete the last line (with `MinLine` parameter) from *MyQuery* in Access, the message gives the proper result as well - does this mean that the problem is somehow connected with the parameter? But I can't get rid of the `MinLine` parameter in *MyQuery*, in fact this is just a subquery of an INSERT-INTO construction.  What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Im not sure what is going on, but the order of the parameters seems to have influence here. MinLine as first parameter and IDLine works for me, IDLine as first and MinLine as Second does not.

Comment: It will prompt or need MinLine and then IDLine, that's logical. MyQuery will be executed first, its paramater is needed first and then TADOQuery. If you keep the sequence of parameters MinLine, IDLine, are you getting result ? or any error/problem ?

Comment: @bummi Thank you! It works. The question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by means of changing the order of the parameters to MinLine, then IDLine. Thank you for the answers.